# How do I undo a git reword that's already been pushed to origin?

Tags: git, github

I did a squash and accidentally reworded someone else's commit, which took place before I made my fork. Now as a result my pull request shows a merge conflict and as 1 commit behind. I want to undo the reword done to that commit, but I dont know how to do that. Here's the pull request: https://github.com/satnogs/satnogs-client-ansible/pull/1

Comment: Haven't tried it, but I suggest a revert (which creates a new commit with the opposite changes) followed by a squash.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your `upstream` and `rebase` your work:
`git rebase upstream/<branch>` (considering your are on your working branch). It will reapply all your commits on top of new `upstream/<branch>`.

Then do force `push` to your `origin`.